# Infinite loop Gif Java

Tags: java, gif

I have able to draw my gif to the frame, and it runs fine. However, once it is finished, the gif just stops. How do I make it restart?

```
        Image icon = new     
        ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/giphy.gif")).getImage();
        g.drawImage(icon,0,0,600,600,this);
```

Comment: icon.getImage.flush();

Comment: use animagic to set an infinite loop.

Comment: Have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566311/displaying-gif-animation-in-java