# Java: show GIF image doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, animated-gif

I'm trying to show a GIF image inside a JLabel using the following code

```
Image waitImage = null;
        JLabel l1;
        try {
            waitImage = ImageIO.read(IndexesPanel.class.getResource("/images/error.gif"));
            l1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(waitImage));
            l1.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 100);
            waitPanel.add(l1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The image is shown, but it's not animated. I'm using the following Gif:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724078/how-do-i-show-a-animated-gif-image-using-a-thread ; after setting up the waitPanel, do the work not on the EDT (event dispatching thread), but in a separate thread. Maybe setting the waitPanel in an `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ... });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ImageIO` returns `BufferedImage`

Use `new ImageIcon(new URL("path to resource"));`

Guess you can use `new ImageIcon(IndexesPanel.class.getResource("/images/error.gif"))`;